# Date content empty when accessing it

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access the date content but to no avail. What happens:

My app:

```
el: "#app",
  data: {
   arrays: [],
   bestc: [],
   todos: [],
  },
beforeCreate(){
axios
      .get("https://api.com/result")
      .then((response) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          this.arrays.push(response.data[i].dezenas);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errored = true;
      })
      .finally(() => computaTudo(this.arrays));

    function computaTudo(array) {
      var content = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        content = content.concat(array[j]);
      }
      return countItems(content);
    }

    function countItems(arr) {
      const countMap = Object.create(null);

      for (const element of arr) {
        // Basicamente, estamos dizendo: atribua à `countMap[element]` o valor
        // atual (ou zero, caso não existir) somado ao número 1.
        countMap[element] = (countMap[element] || 0) + 1;
      }

      this.todos = Object.entries(countMap).map(([value, count]) => ({
        numero: value,
        quantidade: count,
      }));

      return ordeNar();
    }

    function ordeNar() {
      let ordenadoPor = this.todos.slice(0);
      ordenadoPor.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.quantidade - a.quantidade;
      });

      return finished(ordenadoPor);
    }

    function finished(ord){
      let localArr = [];
      localArr = ord.map(function (obj) {
        return obj.numero;
      });

      this.bestc = localArr;
      this.bestc.push();

      if (this.bestc.length > 0) {
        loader.hide();
        this.loading = true;
        console.log(this.bestc)
      }
    }
}
```

On the console **this.bestc** returns exactly the way I want it, but when trying to access via HTML:

```
<div class="lh-1">
        <h1 class="h6 mb-0 text-white lh-1">Números</h1>
        {{ bestc }}
          <small v-for="item in bestc">
            <span class="badge bg-light text-dark">{{ item }}</span>&nbsp; </small>
      </div>
```

It returns empty. I tried different solutions and couldn't find a way to fill it with content. I don't understand why on the console it's working and on the data it's not.

Comment: You’re using `this` in a regular function: it doesn’t refer to the Vue component itself. Use arrow functions instead so the lexical `this` is preserved. Alternatively, instead of defining all these functions inside your beforeCreate lifecycle hook, why not define them as the component methods instead?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Vue, I'm learning it little by little, based on what I find. Thanks!

Comment: Worked with arrow functions! Thanks!